# If $x \neq y$ then $x^n - x! \neq y^n - y!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove the following problem:

> If $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \neq y$ then $x^{2021} - x! \neq y^{2021} - y!$

Following is what I'm thinking of: suppose that $x > y$ and $x^{2021} - x! = y^{2021} - y!$, then

- $gcd(x,y) \neq 1$. Indeed, since $x > y$, $y \mid x!$, that follows
  $y  \mid  x^{2021}$, then $gcd(x,y) \neq 1$.
- the form $x^{2021} - x! = y^{2021} - y!$ can be rewritten as $x^{2021} - y^{2021} = x! - y!$. It suggests that the lifting the exponent lemma may help (but I cannot see it).

Comment: Is $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Your first bullet point can be extended to all prime factors of $y$, meaning that there is some $k$ such that $ y \mid x^k$.

Comment: FYI, I found the more general duplicate using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E%7B2021%7D-x!%5Cneq%20y%5E%7B2021%7D-y!%24&p=1). Since $2^{11}-1=2047$, we can see $2021$ meets the requirements. Also, FYI, there's also [Prove that $f(n)=n^{2007}-n!$ is an Injective Map](/q/3270891), which unfortunately has no answer, and the AoPS thread [Number theory Diophantine](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1662097p10554209), also for exponent $2007$, with it having a link to ...

Comment: (cont.) [Prove that the function n^{2007}-n! is injective](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h150157p848062), which states the source is "Romanian TST $4$ $2007$, Problem $1$". Also, its [Post #$5$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h150157p870233) states "This problem is from BMO'$07$ shortlist (proposed by Serbia)", and then gives the complete solution.